# Symfony 4 services ignored when declared inside a resource file

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Following the official documentation ([here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/import.html#importing-configuration-with-imports)), I decided to split my services.yaml configuration file into several files for readability.

I then created a file config/services/doctrine_listeners.yaml containing this single service definition :

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true     
        autoconfigure: true

    App\Listeners\BookListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist  }
```

And I import it like this in my config/services.yaml :

```
imports:
    - { resource: 'services/doctrine_listeners.yaml' }
```

When proceeding like that, the listener is never instanciated. If I instead declare it directly inside the config/services.yaml it works.

This looks like a bug to me, did I miss something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be that the service is overwritten by the default service file. In it there is a PSR-4 service discovery for all classes in src:

```
# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

This will also register your listeners and it looks like this will overwrite the previous configuration from inside your file.

I would recommend adding `Listeners` to the exclude section in `services.yaml` and then move service discovery for them to your file instead:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true     
        autoconfigure: true

    App\Listeners\:
        resource: '../../src/Listeners/*'

    App\Listeners\BookListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist  }
```

Comment: Your analysis was right, thanks ! I just had to adapt the resource path from your example to '../../src/Listeners' as this file is in a subdirectory, and App\Listeners: needed to be transformed to App\Listeners\:

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have updated the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason would be redundancy in adding your services, which doesn't allows to load the services. It would be great if you share you config/services.yml content here.